# switch using $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] always defaults to first

Tags: php, switch-statement

I have the following code:

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
// CONFIGURATION ITEMS
$captcha_private_key = '';
$captcha_public_key = '';
switch ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {
    case 'earth-neighbours.com' || 'www.earth-neighbours.com':
        $captcha_private_key = '6Lcb_t4SAAAAALkdH4njSny2HYbrmGKS_G84kM_d';
        $captcha_public_key = '6Lcb_t4SAAAAAPEtqJEcWXuo0zmRD5PxYkXx84R4';
        echo 'live';
        break;
    case 'earth-neighbours.projects.mi24.net':
        $captcha_private_key = '6Lca_t4SAAAAAJb5L4sA7fEHxDFA0Jl8jFw-h3hE';
        $captcha_public_key = '6Lca_t4SAAAAAFd-Q2k8esFa9U8nQ2rirEZHFtAH';
        break;
    case 'earth-neighbours.local':
        $captcha_private_key = '6LcZ_t4SAAAAAGc1_S9ahxo-Vg-e7QgHg4yAWBVU';
        $captcha_public_key = '6LcZ_t4SAAAAAPHQDb_f-g4mS6mpmc0heustHQ60&hl';
        echo 'local';
        break;
}
?>
```

It's running on the local server (earth-neighbours.local) so should output 'local'. Instead it outputs 'live'. The echo at the top however (echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];) returns the url earth-neighbours.local so it should be 'local' that is echoed. This has me stumped. I had it working before and now I've shifted it to the top of the page and it doesn't work. Weird! Anyone?

Answer (score 3):

PHP does not do switch case or statements like other programming languages.

When you write the following:

```
 switch ($test) {
   case 1 || 2:
    $blah();
    break;
 }
```

This is what actually happens:

```
 switch ($test) {
   if (true == $test) {
   }
 }
```

The reason this happens is because the case content actually gets evaluated, and in PHP, `1 || 2 === true`. PHP then does a typecast on $test to boolean, and $test, unless empty, comes out true.

The PHP "correct" syntax is:

```
switch ($test) {
  case 1:
  case 2:
    $blah();
    break;
```

In PHP (and a few other languages, actually), once the interpreter gets in the `switch`, the only way it will come out is by `break`. Not breaking at the end of a case tells it to continue.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
case 'earth-neighbours.com':
case 'www.earth-neighbours.com':
```

instead of:

```
case 'earth-neighbours.com' || 'www.earth-neighbours.com':
```

As that is an incorrect syntax for the [**switch statement**](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php)

Comment: actually, `case X || Y:` *is correct syntax*, but its semantics is not what one may expect...

Comment: @alex-shesterov: +1 for the clarification